# Displaying Date from Excel Sheet xlsx in Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, simpledateformat, xssf

I have date saved as 24-Jun-13 in one of cell in Excel sheet(xlsx).
While retriving it is showing me like 174-Jun-2013

The Code is

```
    String ret="";

    if(c.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
    {
        if(col==0)
        {
            ret=new java.text.DecimalFormat("0").format(c.getNumericCellValue());
        }
        else if(col==8)
        {
            if(HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(c))
            {
                DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("DD-MMM-YYYY");
                ret=df.format(c.getDateCellValue());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ret=""+c.getNumericCellValue();
        }
    }   
    else if(c.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
    {
        ret=""+c.getStringCellValue();
    }

    return ret;
```

Please Help me out.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

instead of

```
DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("DD-MMM-YYYY");
```

because:

D = Day in year 
d = Day in month

Answer (score 1):

Check your date pattern: dd/MMM/yyyy should solve your problem.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is documentation where you can find info how to build date patterns properly.

Answer (score 1):

Why not ask Apache POI to do the formatting for you? It will read the format rules applied on the cell in Excel, then format the date based on those

You do this using the [DataFormatter class](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) from Apache POI. Give that a cell, and it'll read the format rules, understand them, then format the cell's value

All you need to do is something like:

```
DataFormatter fmt = new DataFormatter();
String ret = fmt.formatCellValue(cell);
```

This works for numbers, dates, percentages, the works!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("DD-MMM-YYYY");
                ret=df.format(c.getDateCellValue());
```

Via

```
DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-YYYY");
                ret=df.format(c.getDateCellValue());
```